# nested before in rspec doesn't get executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to do the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Artwork do
  before do
     @artwork = Artwork.new(name:  "foo", ...)
  end

  subject { @artwork }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }

  describe "like should be in effect" do
    before do
      this_should_raise_an_error
      @artwork.save!
      let(:liked_user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:liked_user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    end
    expect(@artwork.liked_users_count).to eq(0)
  end
end
```

The this_should_raise_an_error string doesn't raise anything (meaning the before block doesn't get executed?)
And with or without it I get -

```
undefined method 'liked_users_count' for nil:NilClass
```

Which shouldn't happen at all (I should have something in @artwork)

I'm missing something basic in here but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors/misuses in your code, here is what should be done (ask me if its not clear why):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Artwork do

  subject(:artwork) { Artwork.new(name:  "foo", ...) }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }

  describe "like should be in effect" do
    let(:liked_user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:liked_user2) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before do
      this_should_raise_an_error
      artwork.save!
    end

    #either        
    it 'some description' do
      expect(artwork.liked_users_count).to eq(0)
    end

    #or
    its(:liked_users_count) { should eq 0 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, indeed more elgant. My code was inspired by the tutorial in http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.
Can you explain the difference between @artwork init I did and :artwork init you did?

Comment: And although I did noob mistakes about style - Why did the second before didn't get executed?

Comment: using instance variables is bad. your `before` could have been executed, but there were no specs: the `expect` should live within a `it`

Comment: Got it! Many thanks. I guess I need to go back to looking at some more examples becuase clearly I still didn't get the hang of it :)